# acid/water/volume

Tags: volume, ratio

I have a solution that is 50% acid and 50% water. I add 3 pints of pure acid to the solution and find that the solution is now 80% acid and 20% water.  What is the volume of the original container.

Comment: Hi, have you tried anything to solve the problem?

Comment: Kind of stuck with where to start?

Comment: SO would this work:

Comment: x*.5 +3*1.0=(3+x)*.8

Comment: That formula looks right to me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that acid and water do not react together to affect percentages, if the original volume was x pints, how much was acid, how much water? Once you add 3 pints of acid, how much is acid, how much water?

Comment: So would this work? 
x*.5 +3*1.0=(3+x)*.8

Comment: Can you solve that for x? Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes I did Thank you!!